# A query while showing that the Gamma function $\Gamma$ is logarithmically convex for $x \gt 0.$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, logarithms, gamma-function, analytic-functions

We are using the general definition of gamma function defined on $\Bbb C \setminus \{\text{non-positive integers}\}$ i.e. $\Gamma(Z)=\frac {e^{-\gamma z}}{z} \prod (1+ \frac zn)^{-1} e^{\frac zn}$. Note that $\Gamma(x) \gt 0$ on $x \gt 0$.

To show that $\Gamma$ is logarithmically convex on $(0,\infty)$, we first need to show that it is twice differentiable on $x \gt 0$.

> **Query :** Can we say that $\Gamma$ is twice differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ because it is analytic on right half plane? If so then how to prove
>   that? If not so then what is the way?

If we show this then we can differentiate $\log \Gamma(x)$ w.r.t $x$ to get $\frac {d}{dx} \log \Gamma(x)=\frac {\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$ and then by observing $\frac {d^2}{dx^2} \log \Gamma(x) = \left(\frac {\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}\right)' = \frac 1{x^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(n+x)^2} \gt 0$, we can conclude that $\Gamma$ is logarithmically convex on $x \gt 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the infinite product $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-n^{-1}z)^{-1}\exp(z/n)$$ converges uniformly on compact subsets away from the poles $-1,-2,\dots$.  Hence $\Gamma$, being local uniform limit of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}-\{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$, is holomorphic there by Morrera.

Comment: I know this. I want to know whether $\Gamma$  restricted on open interval $(0,\infty)$ is twice differentiable or not...

Comment: Recall holomorphic (i.e. complex analytic) functions are infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Ah I didn't formulated the question correctly. I am very much sorry for that.  I actually wanted to ask that $\log \Gamma(x)$ is also analytic on $\Bbb C - \{0,-1,\cdots\}$. But right hand side of $\log \Gamma(x)$ is an infinite sum. So does $\log \Gamma(x)$ being analytic implies that the infinite sum can be differentiated term by term?

Comment: Yes.  Note that $\log\Gamma(z)$ is an infinite sum of terms of order $(z/n)^2$ (expanding about 0) and the term-by-term derivative, being order z/n^2, is locally absolutely convergent.  So you can differentiate term-by-term (similarly higher derivative).

Comment: So does locally absolutely convergent imply "globally" term by term differentiation?

Comment: Oops, forgot the adjective uniformly in there.  Should be "locally uniformly absolutely convergent".

Comment: Then isn't it that we can do term by term differentiation only locally?

Comment: Differentiation is done locally, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!